# self.topLayoutGuide.length returns sometimes 64 sometimes 20

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I noticed, that after changing the content inset of a UITableView inside a UIViewController, few times, self.topLayoutGuide.length starts returning 64 instead of 20...

The UITabeView is inside a UIViewController, inside a UINavigationController

Important to note, is that self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y is always 20

**Is there a reason why self.topLayoutGuide.length would be 64?**

**How is self.topLayoutGuide.length calculated?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 is height of status bar. 44 is height of Navigation bar (by deafult). That's why topLayoutGuide.length = 64 (20 + 44).

Comment: also the reason is probably the NC hierarchy and handling, as the topLayout might yet not reflect the navigation bar, but later it does